# DAX - CONCATENATEX with FILTER and multiple criteria values in IN clause

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an issue trying to sort out nested CONCATENATEX syntax.

I have an example table like this:

[image: Table with data example]

For each ID I have in my table, I want to list all Connected IDs whenever they are a part of Unique ID.

For example:

- for ID 6613 in my table, I want a column listing 6613, 6614 as they are part of '555-5121' unique ID group.
- for ID 6001 I would expect values - 6001, 6002, 6005, 6006 as 6001 is part of 555-1231 and 555-6612

I have my DAX syntax that works for IDs that are only listed in one group:

```
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (
        'Table1',
        'Table1'[Unique ID]
            IN {
                CONCATENATEX (
                    FILTER (
                        'Table1',
                        'Table1'[Connected IDs] = 'CurrentTable'[ID]
                    ),
                    'Table1'[Unique ID],
                    ","
                )
            }
    ),
    'Table1'[Connected IDs],
    ","
)
```

The above code works fine when the connected id is only linked to one unique id, but brings empty values when there is more than one unique id. When I paste "555-1231", "555-6612" instead of nested CONCATENATEX it lists all 4 connected IDs.

The nested formula also brings correctly separated unique IDs for each ID that I have in my table, it just doesn't want to work when used together (as in the example above).

Is there any clever way to make this work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax isn't working as you're expecting.

The expression `"x" IN { "x,y" }` is not true but `"x" IN { "x", "y" }` is true.

Because of this, you can't use CONCATENATEX to generate a list (it returns a string).

Try something like this instead:

```
VAR UniqueIDs =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            'Table1',
            'Table1'[Connected IDs] = 'CurrentTable'[ID]
        ),
        "UID", 'Table1'[Unique ID]
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER (
            'Table1',
            'Table1'[Unique ID] IN UniqueIDs
        ),
        'Table1'[Connected IDs],
        ","
    )
```

Note that this will list "6001" twice in the applicable rows. To fix that, use SUMMARIZE:

```
VAR UniqueIDs =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            'Table1',
            'Table1'[Connected IDs] = EARLIER ( Table1[Connected IDs] )
        ),
        "UID", 'Table1'[Unique ID]
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                'Table1',
                'Table1'[Unique ID] IN UniqueIDs
            ),
            'Table1'[Connected IDs]
        ),
        'Table1'[Connected IDs],
        ","
    )
```

Comment: Can you help me to answer the concatenx question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76945069/concatenatex-txt-details-with-condition-statement-dax