# CONCATENATEX txt details with condition statement Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to concatenate values based on the condition in DAX measure, not sure how to achieve that, I have tried few dax measure got and struck need help to proceed further. Below is the data and expected result.

Condition I want to apply in concatenate statement is when Delete flag is 'Yes' then remove the Increment text else add text value details as shows in the below table.

[image]

Dax Measure I have tried below, just concatenate without any condition:

```
var __tags =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        VALUES( DATA[Increment]),
           ALLEXCEPT( DATA, DATA[ID],DATA[ITERATION] )
            )

return  
CONCATENATEX(
                __tags,
                DATA[Increment]),
                ", "
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a variable using the `TREATAS` filter to return only records that haven’t been deleted.

```
VAR DeleteStatus = 
TREATAS({“No”}, DATA[Delete])

var __tags =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        VALUES( DATA[Increment]),
           DeleteStatus, 
           ALLEXCEPT( DATA,     DATA[ID],DATA[ITERATION] )
            )

return  
CONCATENATEX(
                __tags,
                DATA[Increment]),
                ", "
            )
```

Comment: looks like it removed all the delete in the previous occurrences ID as well, it will remove delete increment only after that flag get set to 'Yes' not before that.